# Detect if an app is available in app store and is installed on the device

Tags: ios, app-store

I am trying to accomplish the following:

1. Check to see if an app is installed on the device
2. Show user details of the app such as description, rating etc.
3. If it is installed, give user an option to launch it. Else give an option to download it.

Something like the image below. I see many apps showing this standard looking UI. I am not sure if it is provided by the platform.

I looked at how to programmatically detect and launch app using known URI schemes. But I don't see anywhere how to get the description, rating, get the download URL for the app.

Thanks.

[image: Detect and open another app]

Comment: Just to clarify... the screenshot you have provided is from a website that offers a native app, the banner is not produced through a cocoa touch api... These banners are called 'Smart App Banners' and you can find more [info about them here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html)

Comment: This helped. I can try to use smart app banner in my app.